# Javascript object assigning

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, polymorphism

I have an object coming to my VueJS front-end and I need to assign it to a large form with many v-models, which will then submit a new object to the backend. The NEW PARCEL in this photo represents the v-models and the OLD PARCEL is how it is coming from the backend: 
[image]

My problem is I can't find a way to assign the properties to the NEW PARCEL accurately without doing it line by line, as the properties are nested differently based on `address` and `keyedData`:

```
this.newParcel.state = parcel.address.parsed_state
this.newParcel.zip = parcel.address.parsed_postal
this.newParcel.onSiteContactName = parcel.keyedData.onSiteContactName
```

^ Only 4/52! If anyone notices a simpler way to do this, my code would love it! It's quite gnarly to have so many lines of code to achieve the desired effect. 
    this.newParcel.onSiteContactEmail = parcel.keyedData.onSiteContactEmail

Comment: You're looking for [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/assign) which works if the two objects have the same format.

Comment: @EmileBergeron how can you use `Object.assign` to map arbitrarily nested objects from one hierarchy to another?

Comment: Yeah, they don't, so that doesn't work :/

Comment: If you need to flatten the nested objects into one big object, and rename some keys, then you're writting a transformer which applies to this specific case and there's nothing you can do other than manually assign each property.

Comment: The point is, if it's not really needed to rename every property, you could streamline the process with a couple shallow copies with the new object as the target.

Comment: well since it is not a 1-1 mapping you have to do something to map them. Either you copy and paste a lot of you maintain an object with the mappings and do it. There is no easy way to do it.

Comment: I figured it wasn't gonna happen, but wanted to put it out there just in case ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

To make assigning a new structure less verbose, you could create some reference fields, and assign a new object using those.

eg..

```js
const parcel = {
  address: {
    parsed_state: "State",
    parsed_postal: "Postal"
  },
  keyedData: {
    onSiteContactName: "On site contact name"
  }
};

const addr = parcel.address;  //ref var for address
const keyd = parcel.keyedData; //ref var for keyedData

const newParcel = {
  state: addr.parsed_state,
  zip: addr.parsed_postal,
  onSiteContactName: keyd.onSiteContactName
};

console.log(newParcel);
```